# C++ visual studio link multiple libs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, hyperlink, libraries

I have several C++ projects made with visual studio than generates output static libraries: A.lib, B.lib and C.lib

Also I have a project that generates an executable: program.exe.
That executable project links with previous libraries A, B, C and this way it generates program.exe with no problem at all.

Now instead of these 3 I need to generate just one library, so when I build C.lib in additional dependencies of that library I write it depends on A.lib and B.lib, and it builds a bigger C.lib, so far so good.

The problem is when in program.exe is linked with just this bigger C.lib it gets unresolveds, I don't understand the exact reason why this happens.Maybe there is another solution for doing this? I want to be static linked not dll.

Also I've found there is visual studio "lib.exe" that allows composite several .libs into one, but this is command line.

Comment: You can't nest static libs, as there is no "link" step to build these. You can only nest artifacts produced by the linker, i.e. DLL or EXE. You could build a separate lib, "D" that includes the sources of A, B and C.

Comment: For .NET assemblies you can consider using Fody (https://github.com/Fody/Fody) for merging multiple assemblies in to one.  I've come across problems with it in relation to older technologies such as COM and Remoting, but otherwise it pretty much does what you are after.

Comment: I've made a .bat that makes a lib.exe /OUT:D.lib a.lib b.lib c.lib
And thats works, linking with D.lib problem is i have to manually execute the bat. There is some way to automatize this from visual studio?

Comment: Ok I solved with Build Events -> Pre-link events, and calling that .bat from there. Thank you. Solved